# Pyomo Value Error: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object

Tags: pyomo, glpk

I am relatively new to Pyomo and I am testing some energy optimization model at the moment. I can define all the objectives and constraints but when trying to solve I get the following error:

'ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[batt]'

Here is relevant parts of my code (things that I don't think are relevant I just filled with ... to save some space):

```
ders = ["pv", "batt"]

model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var(ders, within = NonNegativeReals)

model.p_pv_load = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)
model.p_pv_grid = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)
model.p_pv_batt = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)

model.p_batt_load = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)
model.p_batt_grid = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)
model.soc_batt = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)

model.p_grid_load = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)
model.p_grid_batt = Var(tsIndex, within = NonNegativeReals)

#obj
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(... for ts in tsIndex)
model.obj = Objective(rule = obj_rule, sense = maximize)

#Some potentially relevant Constraints

maxPV = Constraint(expr = model.x["pv"]<=400)
maxBat= Constraint(expr = model.x["batt"]<=400)

socMin = 0.1*model.x["batt"]
socMax = 0.9*model.x["batt"]
socIni = socMin
batt_pMax=model.x["batt"]/3

#Discharge
def battDisc_rule(model, ts):
    if ts==0:
        return (((model.p_batt_load[ts]+model.p_batt_grid[ts])*(timestep/60))/sqrt(effR_bat) <= model.soc_batt[ts])
    else:
        return (((model.p_batt_load[ts]+model.p_batt_grid[ts])*(timestep/60))/sqrt(effR_bat) <= model.soc_batt[ts-1])
model.battDisc = Constraint(tsIndex, rule = battDisc_rule)

#Charge
def battCh_rule(model, ts):
    if ts==0:
        return ((model.p_pv_batt[ts]+model.p_grid_batt[ts])*(timestep/60))*sqrt(effR_bat) <= socMin-model.soc_batt[ts]
    else:
        return ((model.p_pv_batt[ts]+model.p_grid_batt[ts])*(timestep/60))*sqrt(effR_bat) <= socMin-model.soc_batt[ts-1]
model.battCh = Constraint(tsIndex, rule = battCh_rule)

#Soc

def socBounds_rule(model, ts):
    return inequality(socMin, model.soc_batt[ts], socMax)
model.socBounds = Constraint(tsIndex, rule = socBounds_rule)

def update_SOC(model, ts):
    if ts==0:
        return model.soc_batt[ts]==socIni
    else:
        return model.soc_batt[ts] == model.soc_batt[ts-1]+(((model.p_pv_batt[ts]+model.p_grid_batt[ts]*sqrt(effR_bat))-((model.p_batt_load[ts]+model.p_batt_grid[ts])/sqrt(effR_bat)))*(timestep/60))
model.updateSOC = Constraint(tsIndex, rule=update_SOC)

def chPower_rule(model, ts):
    return model.p_pv_batt[ts]+model.p_grid_batt[ts]*sqrt(effR_bat) <= batt_pMax
model.chPower = Constraint(tsIndex, rule=chPower_rule)

def dchPower_rule(model, ts):
    return model.p_batt_load[ts]+model.p_batt_grid[ts]/sqrt(effR_bat) <= batt_pMax
model.dchPower = Constraint(tsIndex, rule=dchPower_rule)
```

I do not understand the error message since of course x[batt] is uninitialized as it is one of the decision variables.

Weirdly, in Julia's JuMP i can make it run using exactly the same GLPK solver and model description.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to the inequality constraint (inequality(socMin, model.soc_batt[ts], socMax)). I guess the problem is that I try to constrain the bounds of the time dependent decision variable soc_batt with a lower and a higher bound that both depend on the x[batt] --> I will try to change this later and let you know what happend

Comment: I deleted the constraint and just added an upper bound (depending on x[batt] again) since the lower one is given by the within statement to be 0. I do not get the error but therefore solving it gives me lower and upper bounds of infinity...
I guess somewhere I am missing another constraint.

Comment: Saw my mistake! I forgot to add "model" for maxPv and maxBatt. Probably got confused from switching between JuMP and Pyomo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the inequality() constraint function in combination with that I forgot to add "model" to the constraint declaration twice.

Comment: Hi. I am getting a similar erro. Can you show what exact change did  you make?